# How to add the image file name to dynamically added images in a carousel

Tags: jquery

I have used the [carousel from Malsup](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/add.html?v2) to add a carousel to my webpage. What I would like to do in addition is automatically add the file name of each image to the images fed dynamically to the carousel. I change the images regularly, where the quantity of them can also change. I would be very grateful if someone could suggest a way to add the filename of each image to either the bottom of the image (perhaps superimposed on it) or in the space below the image where an "Alt" name would appear.

Thanks in advance for any help you guys can give.
Cheers, David

The markup is as follows:

```
    <div id="slideshow" class="pics">
        <img src="sliderimages/ride_4481.jpg" width="400" height="300" /> 
        <img src="sliderimages/ride_4482.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
```

With CSS styling as follows:

```
     .pics {
            height: 332px;
            width: 432px;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 10px auto;
            display: block;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 8px;
        } 

        .pics img {
            padding: 15px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            background-color: #eee;
            width: 400px;
            height: 300px;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            border-radius: 8px;
        }
```

The script to run the slideshow is (with a lot of comments to serve as reminders:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function() { 
        // start slideshow 
        $('#slideshow').cycle({ 
                fx:      'cover',
            easing: 'easeOutBounce',
            pause: 1,
            speed: 1000,
                timeout:  1500,
            before:   onBefore 
        }); 

        var slidesAdded = false; 

        function onBefore(curr, next, opts) { 
            // Make sure not to call addSlide before it is defined 
            if (!opts.addSlide || slidesAdded) 
                return; 
            // Add slides for images 3 - 8 or whatever number of slides you want to add. Just amend the var i=3; < x; i++ functions below where x is any number.
            // Also ensure you have this number of pictures available or you will get grey placeholders instead!
                // Slides can be a DOM element, a jQuery object, or a string 
             for (var i=3; i < 3; i++) 
             opts.addSlide('<img src="sliderimages/ride_448'+i+'.jpg" width="400" height="300" />');
            slidesAdded = true; 
        }; 
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `after:` event to set the function to replace your caption text. The following code is taken from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/caption.html

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    after:     function() {
        var name = this.src.split('/');
        $('#caption').html(name[name.length-1]);
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9g5G/)**

I'm not entirely sure what the rest of your JavaScript is doing. Why are you adding images on the before event of the carousel?

If you want to make the image alt the filename then use this code:

```
$('#slideshow img').each(function( index ) {
    var name = this.src.split('/');
    this.alt = name[name.length-1];
});

$('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    after:     function() {
        //use the alt tag of the image, which we previously set to the filename above
        $('#caption').html(this.alt);
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9g5G/2/)**

I am taking a guess that the JavaScript `onBefore` function is adding images to your slider, I'm not sure why though because you can just define the images in your html markup to begin with. If for some reason that is the case (maybe you request the images via ajax first). I've added a **[working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/f9g5G/3/)** of that too.

**EDIT**

Seeing as the other question got closed so abruptly...

In order to set up different image sets, there's 2 ways to do it. It's all a matter of setting up the array, or preferably an of JSON describing your image sets or (best) lazy loading the data via an Ajax request on selection of image set. I've already shown you the basic array set up.

Using JSON you could either define all your rides - http://jsfiddle.net/f9g5G/10/:

```
var pictures = {
    ride_443: { 
        ride: 443,
        linkText: "443",
        images: [
            "images/medium/ride_443%20(1).jpg",
            "images/medium/ride_443%20(2).jpg",
            "images/medium/ride_443%20(3).jpg",
            "images/medium/ride_443%20(4).jpg",
            "images/medium/ride_443%20(5).jpg"
        ]
    },
    ride_425: { 
        ride: 425,
        linkText: "443",
        images: [
            "images/medium/ride_425%20(1).jpg",
            "images/medium/ride_425%20(2).jpg"
        ]
    },
    ride_plentong2013: { 
        ride: "plentong2013",
        linkText: "Plentong 2013",
        images: [
            "images/medium/plentong1.jpg",
            "images/medium/plentong2.jpg",
            "images/medium/plentong3.jpg"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or you could load them using AJAX. I'll use the existing XML points as an example, but note that due to [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) I have had to simulate the AJAX call, I put comments in so let me know if you have questions. I have made the assumption that the anchor links for the markup will be generated from server code and not jQuery this time, to match the layout you currently have on the page and group them by year.

http://jsfiddle.net/QzbZ7/

```
var getSliderData = function(group) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/gallery/ride_" + group + "/resources/group.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data) {
            setUpSliders($(data), group);
        }
    });
};

//create the slider
var setUpSliders = function($data, group) {

    var imgBase = "/gallery/ride_" + group + "/resources/";

    $description.html($data.find("galleryDescription").text());

    $data.find("mediaGroup > media > item").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $slideshow.append( 
            $('<img>', { 
                src: imgBase + $this.find("renditions > rendition[size=medium]").attr("src"), 
                alt: $this.find("title").text()
            })
        )
    });

    //set up the slider
    $slideshow.cycle({
        fx:       'fadeZoom',
        timeout:   2000,
        before:     function() { $caption.hide(); },
        after:     function() { $caption.html(this.alt).fadeIn(); }
    });

};

//set up initial slider:
var initialSlider = 443;
getSliderData(initialSlider);
```

Comment: Hi Jammycam, am not sure what code I need to replace in the (this.alt) that you mention. Please also see my comment above. Hope you can spare some time soon. Anyway, thnks in advance.

Comment: I've updated the code and added in code examples. Don't forget to upvote and accept the answer if this helped you :)

Comment: Hi Guys, Many thanks for this. Unfortunately I haven't had time to go over the solutions as I've pulled a muscle in my back and can't sit for more tha a few minutes at a time. Hopefully it will have righted itself by early next week when I'll then be able to take a good look at the answers.

Comment: Hi Jammykam, I've managed to implement the carousel using your "working demo" code (that comes after the ajax remark). It is now doing pretty much what I want of it. I've had an additional thought though..... Would it be possible to have, say, a table of different ride numbers, that when clicked, brought up the carousel for that particular set of pictures? It gets complicated in that the picture sets don't always have the same number of images? If something like that were possible, it would put the icing on the cake! Again, sincere thanks for all your help.

Comment: Depends on where you get your pictures from and how it is set up, up here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/f9g5G/5/ Change the pictures array to add/remove images. Let me know if you have questions.

Comment: Hi Jammykam, that's an excellent solution to the scenario that I set out. Thinking about it a bit more though, it would be quite difficult to administer as the number of images can run to 50 or 60 at times. I'd also need to identify the individual sets by their ride number. At the moment the solution is an Adobe Bridge created slide show that needs Flash. Need to do a non-Flash solution. Please take a look at the current solution http://www.singaporebikehash.com/gallery_pics.html to get a better idea of what I need to do. As ever, very grateful for your help.

Comment: Hi Jammykam, I've been playing with the solution you provided for the carousel with different image sets. How would I change your code to refer to three different locations for image sets to be chosen by the user? Your solution uses images in a single location, which isn't quite what I want to do. Look forward to getting your reply.

Comment: Your image sets appear to be driven from XML, e.g. http://www.singaporebikehash.com/gallery/ride_443/resources/group.xml I would make a call to get the XML and then grab the full image paths, that way you don't need to mess around with manually populating image arrays. I won't have much time until later on the weekend

Comment: To bew honest, I'm not really sure how the images are driven at the moment as I simply use Adobe Bridge to create the image set and the player that you see on the website. What I'd like to be able to do is allow a call to these image sets in some way that allows the viewer to select the ride and then get the picture set in the slider. It would also be fine if only a limited number of sets were available. I've also stumbled on getting the ride number (Ride 447 for examole) to show in place of the "1 2 3" that your code shows for the image sets. Many thanks for your help in all this.

Comment: Hey, could ask a new question with what you have said above (link back to this question) and description of what you need updating. It's getting off track from the original question so would be better as a new question and leave this answer intact. Let me know the link and I'll post answer there. Thanks.

Comment: New question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17161658/how-to-add-images-from-various-sources-to-a-dynamically-loaded-slider as requested. Look forward to your help. Cheers,

Comment: Don't know why that got closed, added it above instead.

Comment: Hi jammykam, that's a really neat solution! I have managed to get it working in Dreamweaver CS6 but can't seem to get the images to load when I use my local WAMP server on Win 7. Any thoughts? Instead of having to build a line of Image sets in the HTML as you have done, is there a way to get the information from the current set of tables that contain the link to the Flash version? If that were possible it would be brilliant since it would allow access to all of the original sets and those that are created in the future. I have to thank you a thousandfold for your help so far. Cheers,

Comment: That's essentially what the last demo does, I've updated to use your existing markup more closely:  http://jsfiddle.net/QzbZ7/2/ It requests the xml data generated by Adobe and then uses that to create the slideshow. Once it is on your server you would uncomment line 22 and delete 27-32

Comment: I've been able to get the code working in Dreamweaver so that clicking on the ride table numbers brings up the correct description and file name captions. However, I'm not getting pictures showing. When I look at the URL generated by the code, it is as follows: <img src="NaN/resources/images/large/ride_443%20(1).jpg" alt="ride_443 (1).jpg" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; z-index: 16; opacity: 0; display: none; "> NaN at the beginning is what I believe is stopping the images showing? Also using "// or the first anchor in the slide groups list" I get 444 not 443; the first?

Comment: Line 41 should end up `var imgBase = url + "/resources/";` (misleading use of english there in my comments, sorry) - http://jsfiddle.net/QzbZ7/15/. Second issue, I'd need to see the end integration result really

Comment: I thought I'd edited that line correctly and it looked the same, but copy pasting your code snippet made it all work! Brilliant, thank you! I've noticed Forward and Back arrows on some sliders. Would it be possible to incorporate this functionality in the design that you have created? Again, a thousand thanks for your help!

Comment: All is working well, except that this code seems not to work: //or the first anchor in the slide groups list
   // $('#slideGroups a:first').trigger('click'); Any thoughts on this? Cheers!

Comment: I assume you mean to advance the images? http://jsfiddle.net/QzbZ7/17/ BTW, make yourself familiar with the documentation and samples: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

Comment: Th click - I think the correct element (443) is being triggered at the start. The sample I set up for you is using the XML specified in the HTML window, I copied this from your server from 444 ride set, it should work correctly once on your server if you follow the instructions I already provided.

Comment: Hi jammykam, many many thanks. The slider is now working as expected with prev and next links. I still have one oddity that is of academic interest. In WAMP server on my local PC, the big gallery runs flawlessly. On the index page where a small version of the code with the ride numbers in the html will only show the grey div that holds the image. No images are loaded. Just can't figure out why the script isn't running. Strange, as the code is virtually the same. Anyway, again a thousand thanks! Am I able to somehow give you kudos?

Comment: On the home page where the images are not called, the Request URL: is http://localhost:9080/gallery/ride_450/resources/group.xml but on the Gallery page where it works it is http://localhost:9080/Hash%20Web%20Unix/gallery/ride_450//resources/images/large/ride_45016.jpg which is clearly why it isn't working in WAMP. But why does it work on the production server? Cheers,

Comment: Most likely the location of the folder of the images is different on each server, so change the location of the img base on line 40 to something like `var imgBase = "/Hash Web Unix/" + url + "/resources/"`. This will give it an absolute path from the root of your website, the previous one was use a relative path (e.g. "a folder called gallery below the current folder"

Comment: I've just used the exact same code in both places now. Though the earlier code with the image locations in the HTML worked in production, I fugured it would be easier to use the exact same code in the gallery and home page. Both work in WAMP now. So once again, a thousand thanks for all your help. If you ever get to Singapore, let me know! Cheers

Comment: Great. Was in Singapore a few years ago, will "pass by" maybe next year. You prob owe me a beer or 2 at Clarke Quay now :)

Comment: Am I able to provide you with an email here? If not, mail the Webmaster on the site! AGain thanks, beer or 3 I'd say!

Comment: Probably not best, you can find me on twitter or [my-username]@gmail.com :)

Answer (score 0):

how about this for html:

```
<div id="slideshow" class="pics">
    <div id="caption"></div>
    <img src="sliderimages/ride_4481.jpg" width="400" height="300" /> 
    <img src="sliderimages/ride_4482.jpg" width="400" height="300" />
```

then JS, instead of this:

```
for (var i=3; i < 3; i++) 
         opts.addSlide('<img src="sliderimages/ride_448'+i+'.jpg" width="400" height="300" />');
        slidesAdded = true;
```

you can do a much more automatic way

```
$(".pics img").each(function(){
$(this).attr("alt", $(this).href)
opts.addSlide($(this));
});
```

then you can add what jammycam suggested

```
    $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:       'fadeZoom',
    timeout:   2000,
    after:     function() {
        $('#caption').html(this.alt);
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for such a swift reply. I've tried to get this working, but am failing miserably. I'm not at all sure what code jammycam wants to substitute for (this.alt)? At present all I can get to work is a slider that uses the initial two images and which continues ad infinitum. What can I be doing wrong as I copy-pasted the code from here. Look forward tohearing what you guys think I may be doing wrong.

Comment: `$(this).attr("alt", $(this).href)` will not work, these are not anchor links, they are images. Why cast `$(this).href` to a jQuery object when you can just use `this.href` anyway? What you wanted was `this.src`.